# Is Volatile.Read / Volatile.Write for "double" atomic?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.5, volatile, thread-synchronization

MSDN states that:

> Reads and writes of other types, including `long`, `ulong`, `double`, and `decimal`, as well as user-defined types, need not be atomic.

[C# 7.0 draft specification - Variables - 9.6 Atomicity of variable references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#96-atomicity-of-variable-references)

Will [`Volatile.Write(Double, Double)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.write#system-threading-volatile-write(system-double@-system-double)) work as atomic operation?  If so how this is guaranteed?

Is it safe to do `Volatile.Write(ref mydouble, value);` in one thread and `Volatile.Read(ref mydouble)` in another where `mydouble` has `double` type?

That was general question. Another question - what should I do in this particular situation:

- 2 processors Xeon x64 server
- Windows + MS .NET 4.5
- read/write double from different threads
- SMALLEST latency (need smallest because i'm writing HFT software)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `Volatile` is not atomic, and it is not safe in an SMP (>1 processor) system to assume so. It is safe on a uniprocessor machine.

Unless you **really** need the performance, you probably want `Interlocked` instead, either `Interlocked.Exchange` or `Interlocked.Read`.

Comment: what's the problem with `Volatile.Write/Volatile.Read` ?

Comment: btw the question is if `Volatile.Write/Volatile.Read` is atomic for double so I can't mark your answer as correct as you didn't answered my question.

Comment: @javapowered personally, I'm not aware of any guarantee that "volatile" (for double) suggests atomic. Hence, I would personally *only* use "Interlocked" if I was doing lock-free access. In fact,  use Interlocked *even on x64*, where (as a side-effect of the chip size) it almost certainly *is* atomic. Hence I have to agree that "use Interlocked" is the most appropriate answer to the question.

Comment: It's the other way around, atomic is a stronger guarantee than volatile. The latter guarantees you get a memory barrier, but it doesn't guarantee against different processors seeing different values due to cache hits. Atomic guarantees that if two processors are operating on the same memory address, that they really are seeing the same thing

Comment: @MarcGravell when "Volatile" class should be used? it become useless. just always use "Interlocked"?

Comment: @javapowered for the types that are atomic, volatile has sme uses - but frankly, volatile is hugely misunderstood, generally; instruction reordering is complex. I would advise using Interlocked or a "lock" - easier to get right.

Comment: @MarcGravell i just don't want to use `Interlocked` unless I have to. because i'm writing time-sensetive software (see updated version of my question). Also I wonder why `Volatile` class was added to .NET 4.5. I want to know the scenarios it supposed to use.

Comment: @javapowered the volatile keyword shares a lot in common with its "c" equivalent. To use it correctly, you need to understand the memory model ampnd cpu for your target platform. Most common uses of volatile are dubious, IMO.

Comment: Volatile is more important in high-performance code on ARM, which makes sense why it was added to .NET 4.5, where you don't have x86 ordering guarantees *and* CPU perf matters more. Honestly, if you're down to caring about stuff like Volatile vs. Interlocked, you're probably also down to rewriting the code in C++, where you'll get way better predictability about things like cache line hits/misses. But, Xeon CPUs are *really* fast. I'd try to minimize IO and page faults before I worried about Volatile

Comment: If you evoke even a *single* extra page fault, it wipes out the gains of literally *tens of thousands* of Volatile calls. Page faults and optimizing memory locality (i.e. arrays vs Lists) will get you way more perf benefit. Read up on some of the stuff the XNA people recommend for optimizations, they've got a lot of good stuff about this.

Comment: @MarcGravell I thought it was a common misunderstanding that people think Interlocked is not atomic for larger than 32bit values because of a statement in the MSDN documentation.  However it all depends on the architecture that its run on.  Interlocked is atomic for 64 bit value types if it is run on x64.  I largely suspect volatile is the same (i.e. atomic for double/long/8 byte value types on x64 systems).  More here, http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx.  PS I reached that conclusion by looking at what APIs are called, I am 100% certain Interlocked is atomic for 8 byte values on x64

Comment: @PaulBetts do you have any good links about the XNA recommended optimizations?

Comment: @AnaBetts Sorry to resurrect, but atomic is not a "stronger guarantee than volatile". Volatile is about ordering of access to *different* memory locations, and interlocked provides atomicity, which is about the consistency of operations on a *single* memory address. One is not stronger than the other, they're orthogonal properties. In .Net, volatile provides acquire/release semantics, but no additional atomicity guarantees. Interlocked provides atomicity, but doesn't specify any ordering, except for the MemoryBarrier method. Honestly, the whole thing's a bit of a mismatched system.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, the documentation (and/or implementation) of the [`Volatile` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile?view=net-7.0) have since been updated, stating now:

> The Volatile class also provides read and write operations for some 64-bit types such as Int64 and Double. Volatile reads and writes on such 64-bit memory are atomic even on 32-bit processors, unlike regular reads and writes.

So `Volatile.Read` and `Volatile.Write` on 64 bit values **are in fact atomic, even on 32 bit systems**.

**However**, note that reads and writes performed with the `Volatile` class are not the same as reads/writes using `volatile` fields. So accessing 64 bit `volatile` fields **is not atomic**, while using the `Volatile` class **is atomic**.
From the [`volatile` (keyword) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile):

> Other types, including double and long, cannot be marked volatile because reads and writes to fields of those types cannot be guaranteed to be atomic. To protect multi-threaded access to those types of fields, use the Interlocked class members or protect access using the lock statement.

Interestingly enough, the `Volatile` class isn't mentioned here for atomic access, I would personally say that this part of the documentation is a bit outdated.

Comment: *"So accessing 64 bit `volatile` fields is not atomic"*. -- You can't even mark 64 bit fields as `volatile`. The C# compiler doesn't allow it. So making statements about the characteristics of 64 bit `volatile` fields is like making statements about the biology of unicorns!