# are reads and writes to a variable of type double guaranteed to be atomic on a 64 bit intel processor?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a 64 bit machine running a 64 bit processor but my application is 32 bit. Is reading or writing to a double guaranteed to be atomic? I am talking about assignment and reading only. How does a 32 bit process affect this process? Can the reader ever read partial value from a double when other thread is writing to it in given specs?

Comment: No, _"[Reads and writes of \[...\] long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278%28VS.71%29.aspx)"_. See also [Does Volatile.Read / Volatile.Write for “double” atomic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435325/does-volatile-read-volatile-write-for-double-atomic).

Comment: @CodeCaster this is from VS03 (not VS13) and from the C# language spec. The 64 bit CLR can give additional guarantees if it pleases to do so.

Comment: If the double is aligned (i.e. on an 8 byte boundary), then reads and writes are atomic. That's true on both 32 and 64 bit architectures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  A *double* can easily straddle the L1 cache line boundary, requiring multiple bus cycles to glue the two pieces together.  A very real problem in C#, the 32-bit CLR only provides an alignment guarantee of 4.

These misaligned accesses are not only not atomic, they are also expensive due to the shuffling the processor needs to do.  Code that uses double can have 3 distinct timings, fast if the double happens to be aligned to 8 by accident, twice as slow when it is misaligned to 4 but still inside an L1 cache line, over three times slower when it is misaligned across a cache line.  Such a program can randomly bump into one of these modes when the garbage collector compacts the heap and moves the double.  Be **very** wary of this, a synthetic test program can easily miss this failure mode.

The perf problem is the core reason that a double[] is allocated in the Large Object Heap much sooner normal.  The LOH provides an alignment to 8 guarantee.  The normal rule is for objects >= 85,000 bytes, for double[] in 32-bit mode it is 8,000 bytes (1000 elements in the array).

You *must* use Interlocked.Exchange() if you need the atomicity guarantee.  And I ought to post the disclaimer that atomicity is a very weak guarantee and no substitute for proper locking when requried.

Comment: Is it really the case that doubles are not aligned? That must have an appalling impact on performance.

Comment: I discovered this the Hard Way™ :)  And got to like the x64 jitter a lot more.

Comment: I am allocating an array of about 100 to 500 `doubles` using `GCAlloc` as `gch = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);`. Would this be aligned as expected?

Comment: Not sure what you "expected".  That doesn't allocate anything but an extra handle that convinces the GC to not destroy or move the array.  Alignment is still to 4, it just never changes since you pinned it.

Comment: apologies. `data` is basically an array of `doubles` defined as `data = new double[200];`. In this case do we know that these doubles are 8 byte aligned?

Comment: Please review the answer, I explicitly covered that.  200 < 1000.