# Difference between Threading.Volatile.Read(Int64) and Threading.Interlocked.Read(Int64)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile, interlocked

What is the difference, if any, of the `Read(Int64)` method of the .NET system classes [`System.Threading.Volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.read?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Volatile_Read_System_Int64__) and [`System.Threading.Interlocked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.read?view=netframework-4.8)?

Specifically, what are their respective guarantees / behaviour with regard to (a) atomicity and (b) memory ordering.

Note that this is about the `Volatile` class, *not* the `volatile` (lower case) keyword.

---

The MS docs state:

> #### Volatile.Read Method
>
> Reads the value of a field. On systems that require it, inserts a
>   memory barrier that prevents the processor from reordering memory
>   operations as follows: If a read or write appears after this method in
>   the code, the processor cannot move it before this method.
>
> ...
>
> Returns `Int64`
>
> The value that was read. This value is the latest written by any processor 
>   in the computer, regardless of the number of processors or the state of 
>   processor cache.

vs.

> #### Interlocked.Read(Int64) Method
>
> Returns a 64-bit value, loaded as an atomic operation.

Particularly confusing seems that the `Volatile` docs do not talk about atomicity and the `Interlocked` docs do not talk about ordering / memory barriers.

Side Note: Just as a reference: I'm more familiar with the [C++ atomic API](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load) where atomic operations always also specify a memory ordering semantic.

---

The [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166019/c-sharp-bool-is-atomic-why-is-volatile-valid) (and transitive links) helpfully provided by [Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507457/difference-betweeen-threading-volatile-readint64-and-threading-interlocked-rea#comment101482905_57507457) do a good job of explaining the difference / ortogonality of volatile-as-in-memory-barrier and atomic-as-in-no-torn-reads, but they do not explain how the two concepts apply to these two classes.

- Does `Volatile.Read` make any guarantees about atomicity?
- **Does `Interlocked.Read` (or, really, any of the `Interlocked` functions) make any guarantees about memory order?**

Comment: Pro'lly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435325/does-volatile-read-volatile-write-for-double-atomic

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166019/c-sharp-bool-is-atomic-why-is-volatile-valid) is also can be helpful, with reference to Eric Lippert articles

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - thanks for the link. It's a good one, and sheds some light on to the concepts, but it doesn't IMO, really answer the question with regard to the two concrete .NET classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Interlocked.Read` [translates into a CompareExchange operation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Interlocked.cs#L138):

```
public static long Read(ref long location)
{
    return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref location, 0, 0);
}
```

Therefore it has all the benefits of CompareExchange:

- Full memory barrier
- Atomicity

`Volatile.Read` on the other hand has only acquire semantics. It helps you ensuring the execution order of your read operations, without any atomicity or freshness guarantee.

Comment: Thanks. Strangely enough, the .NET docs never seem to mention anything about the memory barrier. I guess one can *assume* that these are implemented in terms of the [Win32/Intrinsic equivalents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange) where they do state this explicitly. What do you think?

Comment: @MartinBa I assume both are implemented the same way (with a `lock cmpxchg` instruction), so it's fair to compare them. The .net documentation is very bad (and sometimes even wrong) when it comes to describing the memory model.

Comment: Do you happen to know why there's no `Interlocked.Read(ref int arg)` then? Surely memory barrier + atomicity on `Int32` is needed, especially on 32-bit architectures, where interlocked `Int64` read would be quite complicated and thus expensive.

Comment: As I understand it, that's because atomicity is guaranteed for `Int32` on both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures without the need for `Interlocked`. Therefore you only need to use `Volatile.Read(ref int arg)` to get the same guarantees. I believe that on 64-bit architectures, `Interlocked.Read()` is equivalent to `Volatile.Read()`, as atomicity is already guaranteed.

Comment: How do you get freshness guarantee in .NET if the memory is mapped read only (`Interlocked.Read` fails in that case)?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of the [`Volatile.Read(long)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.read#system-threading-volatile-read(system-int64@)) method doesn't mention anything about atomicity, but the atomicity of all `Volatile` operations is [explicitly guaranteed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile#remarks) in the documentation of the `Volatile` class:

> The `Volatile` class also provides read and write operations for some 64-bit types such as `Int64` and `Double`. Volatile reads and writes on such 64-bit memory are atomic even on 32-bit processors, unlike regular reads and writes.

Also the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Volatile.cs#L88-L96) of the `Volatile.Read(long)` is revealing:

```
private struct VolatileIntPtr { public volatile IntPtr Value; }

[Intrinsic]
[NonVersionable]
public static long Read(ref readonly long location) =>
#if TARGET_64BIT
    (long)Unsafe.As<long, VolatileIntPtr>(ref Unsafe.AsRef(in location)).Value;
#else
    // On 32-bit machines, we use Interlocked, since an ordinary volatile read
    // would not be atomic.
    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Unsafe.AsRef(in location), 0, 0);
#endif
```

- On 32-bit machines, the `Volatile.Read` method invokes indirectly the `Interlocked.CompareExchange`, just like the [`Interlocked.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.read) does ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Interlocked.CoreCLR.cs#L173-L174)), so there is no difference between the two. A full fence is emitted by both methods.
- On 64-bit machines the atomicity of the reading is guaranteed by the CPU architecture, so a cheaper half fence is emitted instead.

So the `Volatile.Read` should be the preferable option in most cases, unless you need the full memory barrier provided by the `Interlocked` APIs. The `Volatile` APIs normally provide half fences only, that are adequate for getting acquire / release semantics ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275/when-should-the-volatile-keyword-be-used-in-c/77423332#77423332)).

**Note:** the [`Intrinsic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388664/what-does-the-intrinsic-attribute-in-c-sharp-do) attribute means that the code of the decorated method can be potentially replaced/optimized by the Jitter. This could be concerning, in case the atomicity was not guaranteed explicitly in the documentation.