# Inconsistency between Volatile and Interlocked

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, volatile, interlocked

Below is the source code:

```
public static class Volatile
{
   // ...
   public static ulong Read(ref ulong location);
   public static long Read(ref long location);
   public static double Read(ref double location);  
}

public static class Interlocked
{
   // ... Interlocked has only two Read methods as below:
   public static ulong Read(ref ulong location);
   public static long Read(ref long location);   
}
```

I have some questions here, why there is no counterpart "Read double" method in `Interlocked`?

And what's the difference between `Volatile`'s "Read long" with `Interlocked`'s "Read long".

Comment: Related: [Difference between Threading.Volatile.Read(Int64) and Threading.Interlocked.Read(Int64)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507457/difference-between-threading-volatile-readint64-and-threading-interlocked-read)

Comment: Not exactly.  Source code [is here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/volatile.cs,189)

Comment: @HansPassant the link you posted  is Volatile's Read double method, but there is no couterpart in Interlocked

Answer (score 2):

Volatile and Interlocked have different functions, so you should not use words like "inconsistency" or "counterpart".

#### Interlocked.Read

Reading a 64-bit number in a 32-bit program isn't atomic, e.g.

| Thread1 | Thread2 |
| --- | --- |
| `a = 0x100000002L;` | `long b = a;` |

In a 32-bit program, you have a certain probability of reading results that have only been updated by half, i.e. `0x100000000L` or `2`. `Interlocked.Read` ensures that you can only read `0` or `0x100000002L`.

If you are still developing 32-bit programs and you need a `Interlocked.Read(double)` method, you can use `CompareExchange` instead:

```
double d = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref doubleValue, 0, 0);
```

#### Volatile

For statements that read and write data, the compiler or processor may optimize the order of execution to improve memory access efficiency, e.g.

| Thread1 | Thread2 |
| --- | --- |
| `x1 = 1;` | `y2 = y1;` |
| `y1 = 2;` | `x2 = x1;` |

If you don't use `Volatile`, you have a chance to see `y2 == 2` and `x2 == 0`, this is because `y1 = 2` may have been executed before `x1 = 1`. So you need to use `Volatile` to prevent the execution order from being changed.

| Thread1 | Thread2 |
| --- | --- |
| `Volatile.Write(ref x1, 1);` | `y2 = Volatile.Read(ref y1);` |
| `y1 = 2;` | `x2 = x1;` |